# QGIS: Select Lines within a polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, clip

I would like to select all lines within a polygon. I tried to do that with the clip-function, but it didn't work out (the resulting layer was empty). Do I have to select a particular setting before using that function or why isn't it working?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @leni! You could try using the **Select by location** tool and choose `intersects` as the _Geometric predicate_ :)

Comment: Hey Joseph, thanks for your answer! At first this didn't work either, but then I changed the coordinate system to WGS84. Now the "clip" function as well as "salect by location" work

Comment: Most welcome! Yes, you need to make sure the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) for both layers are the same in order to get the most accurate results =)